# Python: Making dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way where I can make my data frame (using pandas) like this?
[expected data frame format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6B2N.png)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/11301900

Comment: Do you have a specific question? What have you done already?

Comment: I don't have anything solid as I was trying to manipulate my dataframe to look as such for a long time. Coming here was my last resort..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One way of doing it

```
data = []
for variableX in ['M','N','O','P']:
    for variableY in [1,2]:
        data.append([variableX, variableY])

data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['variableX', 'variableY'])
data = data.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([data.variableX.unique(), data.variableY.unique()])).T
new_index=['variableX', 'variableY','variableZ']
data.reindex(new_index)
```

**Output**

```
              M              N               O               P
              1     2        1       2       1       2       1      2
variableX   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
variableY   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
variableZ   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```